# Why do "Properties" and df command return different used disk space?

Tags: ssd, disk-usage, df

So I just formatted two SSDs to EXT4 and when I right-click and select Properties in file manager, I get a window that says 50 GB (!) of disk space is already used on the 1 TB disk and 100 GB (!!) is used on the 2 TB disk.

The df command hower indicates only 77 MiB are used on each.

Anyone know the reason for this discrepancy and how to determine the real values of available space?

Many thanks

[image: Screen captures]

Comment: Look into "ext4 reserved space".  By default, ext4 reserves 5% of space for root only.  `df` does not display this space.  The reserved space can be tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, thanks Andrew. I reduced the space reserved for superuser to 2% using
`sudo tune2fs -m2 /dev/sdc1`